# Is there a short word or slang for "matchmaker"?

Tags: slang, synonyms

I'm trying to find an appropriate name for kind of a dating website. The purpose of the website is to match between people, hence the description - matchmaker. However this word isn't catchy enough.

Any suggestions for some catchy, appealing and "cute" word?

Comment: In Hebrew, the word for a matchmaker is "shadchan" -- which is also the word for a stapler. Not necessarily an answer, but it's certainly cute.

Comment: Stapler is indeed cute, but too long.
Actually in Hebrew the word "click" is a slang for a spark between two people. I thought of using - "clicker", i.e. the one who makes love sparks. But it doesn't have any good meaning in English. Or does it...?

Comment: Clicker: Person who distributes copy and oversees placement of text (Printing); head shoemaker who cuts out the upper part of a shoe and gives it to other workers; T.V. remote control device (Slang).

Comment: It has too many other meanings to be truly useful, but in Bujold's Barrayar, a matchmaker is called a Baba. :)

Comment: "Heart Attach" - Ok, it's not cute enough and probably too cheeky/morbid to work as an answer. But come on, it's memorable :P.

Comment: "Yente" was the name of the village matchmaker in *Fiddler on the Roof*.

Answer (score 5):

**Cupid** might be a good idea.

**Play Cupid**: to try to arrange for two people to fall in love.

> He was playing cupid when he introduced John to Sheila.

According to [ldoce](http://www.ldoce.com):

> a character based on the Roman god of sexual love, who was the son of Venus. Cupid is usually shown in pictures as a young boy with wings, holding a  bow  and  arrow . His picture is often used on  Valentine card s  to represent love. People sometimes say that they have been hit by Cupid's arrow when they have started to have romantic feelings for someone.

Accroding to [MSN Dictionary](http://encarta.msn.com/encnet/features/dictionary/DictionaryResults.aspx?search=matchmaker&lextype=2):

> Synonyms for matchmaker: marriage broker, go-between, fixer, intermediary, cupid

Comment: *Eros* (the Greek god) would be a sexier version of Cupid.

Comment: My goal is to find a catchy website name and cupid is already taken and also I think it's too straightforward and doesn't differentiate itself good enough.

Comment: And "Eros" has less of a romantic association these days and more of a sexual one; unless you're specifically advertising as a hookup service I think I'd avoid it.

Comment: Agreed - Cupid is too obvious. The suggestion of "Stapler" above is the kind of clever wordplay called for here. "Click" is also snappy, and people who are a good fit are said to "click together." But that's undoubtedly trademarked already. Consider the success of Ashley Madison - the site does not need a name that reflects its function, it just needs a good name, period.

Answer (score 1):

Here is are some words:

> **proxy**
>   **cupid**

Comment: *Proxy* is a fun word, but it makes me think of *love surrogate*, which is essentially a sex professional.

Answer (score 0):

Continuing the stapler theme, how about

> www.gluelove.com

as a play on "true love" (rather than a solvents problem...)